# Fast in SSMS and slow in the application - Why does it take this DataSet so long to fill?

Tags: .net, sql, ado.net, dataset

I have a dataset which is filled from a query as follows...

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF, dbo.CustomFunction(ColA) AS ColG
FROM    TableA
    JOIN ViewA ON ColA = ViewColA 
WHERE   ColB = @P1 AND ColC = @P2 AND ColD = @P3 AND ColE = @P4 
ORDER BY ColB, ColC DESC, ColA
```

(Query fields etc obfuscated)

I have profiled this query and it returns around 200 rows in 12 seconds running in SSMS. Note that I restarted the server and used the required DBCC commands to ensure that an existing execution plan wasnt used.

However, when I run this query from my .Net application it takes over 30 seconds to fill the dataset and times out on the default ADO.Net command time out of 30 seconds.

If the query runs in 12 seconds, I just cannot see why it should take more than 18 more seconds to fill 200 rows into a dataset. Unless there is something going on here that I dont know about. I imagine that ADO.Net just calls the query, gets the data and populates it.

The population code looks like this (note I have inherited this from another developer)...

```
DataSet res = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            var cmd = new SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            String params = FillParameters(cmd, _params, params);
            cmd.CommandText = params + SQL;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Transaction = _transaction;

            if (CommandTimeout.HasValue)
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout.Value;
            }

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(res);
            return res;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Running this in debug, when the fill method is hit the method takes around 50 seconds to complete. This is proved by setting a high time out on the ADO.Net command. I am happy with the performance of the query which I can run consistently in around 12 seconds so why the additional 18+ seconds to populate the dataset?

Is ADO.Net doing something (possibly due to the structure) of this code that means it takes more than 18 seconds to populate the dataset? I have tried setting EnforceConstraints to false and that makes no difference.

One thing to note is that due to the design of this program, more than the required numbers of parameters are fed into sql command. The FillParameters method does this. There are 20 or so "default" parameters that are added to the command but only e.g. 4 are used by this query.

So in summary,

- What could be happening to make it take 18+ seconds to fill the DS?
- Is ADO.Net doing something "clever" with my dataset rather than just running the query and populating the data set?
- Could it be the excessive amount of parameters passed in that is causing the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats going on on this line ->  cmd.Transaction = _transaction; ADO.NET commands support transactions but transactions are most efficient performed on the server, i.e. using BEGIN TRANSACTION in a proc.

Comment: @kd7 - in this scenario _transaction is null it shouldnt be affecting anything. This is a generic procedure I am looking at used in a number of places. I think when it is used for updates a transaction can be passed in to this.

Comment: Are you running with the same connection settings? In particular what is the transaction isolation level in the call from .Net? Connection settings such as transaction isolation level can affect the time of the query. Also, I think 12 seconds is a very long time, unless you have tens or hundreds of millions of rows. Do consider better indexes.

Comment: @Ben - the query is fine as there is a lot of data to process. What I dont understand is how it can only take 12 seconds to run the query, yet another 28+ seconds for ADO.Net to populate that data into a Dataset?

Comment: Are you running with the same connection settings? In particular what is the transaction isolation level in the call from .Net? Connection settings such as transaction isolation level can affect the time of the query.

Comment: No transaction isolation level is set at present. Could that be a difference - SMSS uses one level as standard and ADO.Net is using another?

Comment: ADO needs to determine the schema, it could be that this takes quite some time depending on the types and constraints on the columns. You could load the schema first (time that) and then load the data.

Comment: Find out the transaction isolation level of the process from `select transaction_isolation_level,*
from sys.dm_exec_sessions' Session_id is the SPID of the session. host_name and program_name will help identify the correct session from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the existing code was enforcing a Serializable isolation level.

I compared using SQL Server Profiler the commands and execution stats from both the query running through SSMS and the appliction.

```
--- SSMS ---
....
....
set transaction isolation level read committed

CPU: 7797
Reads: 338,425
Writes: 1685
Duration: 7,912

--- Application ---
....
....
set transaction isolation level serializable 

CPU: 46,531
Reads: 241,202
Writes: 0
Duration: 46,792
```

I then ran the query in SSMS using both `Set transaction isolution level serializable` AND `exec sp_executesql` so that SQL Server had no hints from SSMS as to what the query contained.

This reproduced the execution time of 30+ seconds in both SSMS and the application.

It was then just a case of modifying the code to use a `Read Committed` isolation level.

References:
http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#otherreasons

Answer (score 0):

Assume your tables have primary keys

1) check existing indexes fragmentation
  if fragmentation is more than 30%, rebuild index otherwise reorganize
2) check missing index columns
  create non-cluster indexes based on missing columns

Then re-run your sql script. Generally should improve after managing proper indexes.

Comment: The query is ok. Its ADO.Net that for some reason is taking more time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem isn't in the code but in the database, if you have a big database then probably this is your problem, try to update the statistics in your database using this:

> EXEC sp_updatestats

Comment: No its not that - the query runs in 12 seconds. ADO.Net is taking the rest of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing SET ARITHABORT ON in your query. It did solve my problem

Comment: Why delete your answer, and then post the exact same answer a second time?